# default choice of contrast for factors

Tags: contrasts

In John Fox's and Sanford Weisberg's "An R companion to applied regression" (2nd edition) I read on page 215: "Helmert coding is currently rarely used, although it **was the default method** for coding in some older computer programs". Why is it rarely used? I think it being orthogonal (if the number of observations is equal at each level) makes it the perfect choice for a contrast. As long as you don't have a specific hypothesis as to what combination of levels compares how with another disjoint combination, I consider it a perfect default choice. In [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264288/why-do-contrasts-in-r-default-to-dummy-codes) it is argued, that the interaction encoding of two binary factors is much more intuitive when using `contr.sum()` (which is the same as `contr.helmert()` for two level factors). I'd like to add that with that coding you get the same results for an Anova with type II and type III sums of squares. So why is helmert not a good choice anymore for **default** contrasts?